# How can I solve the error of "Invalid Credentials"?

Tags: laravel

I'm creating an App with Laravel and I have being having challenges authenticating admin. I created controllers for both Admin and regular users. I also created different auth pages for them. The users can register and login fine but the admin is throwing "invalid credentials" even when I'm registering new admin or when trying to login. I have checked everything including the routes, I couldn't find anything that could have caused.

I have debugged by using "dd" to check the credential passed and it coming out as the right dataset. Here are my code base:

My Routes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AboutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CollectionsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UsersController;
use App\Models\User;
use Filament\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);

Route::get('/about', [AboutController::class, 'about']);

Route::get('/collections/{category}', [CollectionsController::class, 'show']);

Route::get('/contact', [ContactController::class, 'contact'])->name('pages.contact');

Route::post('/contact', [ContactController::class, 'sendMessage'])->name('pages.contact.send');

// Admin auth routes 
Route::middleware('guest:admin')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/admins/register', [AdminController::class,'create'])->name('admins.register');
    
    Route::get('/admins/login', [AdminController::class, 'login'])->name('admins.login');
  
  });
  
  Route::middleware('auth:admin')->group(function () {
  
    Route::post('/admins/logout', [AdminController::class,'logout'])->name('admins.logout');
    
    Route::get('/admins/dashboard', [AdminController::class,'dashboard']);
  
  });


// Auth routes
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {

  Route::get('/register', [UsersController::class,'create']);
  
  Route::get('/login', [UsersController::class, 'login'])->name('login');

  Route::get('/admins/register', [AdminController::class,'create'])->name('admins.register');

  Route::get('/admins/login', [AdminController::class, 'login'])->name('admins.login');
  
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {

  Route::post('/logout', [UsersController::class,'logout']);

  Route::get('/users/dashboard', [UsersController::class, 'dashboard']);

});

// Registration routes
Route::post('/admins/register', [AdminController::class, 'store'])->name('admins.register');

Route::post('/users', [UsersController::class,'store']);

// Login routes
Route::post('/admins/login', [AdminController::class,'authenticate'])->name('admins.dashboard');
Route::post('/users/login', [UsersController::class, 'authenticate'])->name('users.dashboard');
```

My AdminController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;


class AdminController extends Controller

// Here is a reference snippet of code from app/Http/Controllers/AdminsController.php:


{

    //Show register/create form
    public function create(){
        return view('admins.register');
    }

    // Store a new admin_user
    public function store(Request $request){
        //Validate the form data
        $attributes = $request->validate([
            'name' =>['required', 'min:3'],
            'email' => ['required','email', Rule::unique('admins', 'email')],
            'password' => ['required','min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    
        //Hash the password
        $attributes['password'] = bcrypt($attributes['password']);
    
        //Create and save the admin_user
        $admin = Admin::create($attributes);
    
        // Login the admin_user
        auth()->login($admin);
            return redirect()->route('admins.login')->with('message', 'Admin created successfully!');
    }

       //Show Logout Form
       public function logout(Request $request){
        auth()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return redirect('/admins/login')->with('message', 'Admin logged out successfully!');
    }

   // Show Admin Login Form
   public function login()
   {
       return view('admins.login');
       }

    // Authenticate the admin_user
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the form data
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required', 'min:6'],
        ]);
    
        // Attempt to authenticate the admin
        if (auth()->guard('admin')->attempt($credentials, $request->filled('remember'))) {
            // Redirect to the admin dashboard
            return redirect()->intended('/admins/dashboard');
        }
    
        // If it reaches here, authentication failed
        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'Invalid credentials'
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }    

     //Admin dashboard
     public function adminDashboard(){
        return view('admins.dashboard');
    }

    //Show admin Dashboard
    public function dashboard(){
        return view('admins.dashboard');
    }


}
```

My Admin Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Admin extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'admins';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password','remember_token'];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];    
}
```